# Consuming Oracle advanced queues from BizTalk

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk, advanced-queuing

I am in a situation where I need to consume messages from an Oracle AQ into my BizTalk server. A third party will en-queue the messages and the BizTalk server is supposed to de-queue and consume them. I read over the internet and MSDN and all and found out that there is no direct way to consume AQ from BizTalk.

Am I missing something here?

What options do I have if I want to consume the AQ in BizTalk?

I am considering writing stored procedures to do that for me and then i call the stored procedures, or maybe a WCF service that sits in the middle of AQ and BizTalk server. But I just want to know the experts advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for anyone with a similar problem in the future, i created two stored procedures in oracle for enqueueing and dequeueing the messages to and from oracle AQ and i called those stored procedures from biztalk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to direct consume Oracle AQ from BizTalk, using the third party [JMS Adapter for BizTalk](https://jnbridge.com/software/jms-adapter-for-biztalk/overview) from JNBridge. This is however a paid component, but they provide a 30 day trial.